# Which degree should be used?

Tags: adverbs, homework

Which degree of 'less' is correct in the following sentence -
"Seats in this room are much *less/lesser* in comparison to the adjacent one."

Also please state any general rule of English if it is being applied here.
Thanks.

Comment: Many would say that there is a grammatical error in using the quantifier _less_ rather than _fewer_ with a count noun. _Lesser_ is only distantly related, an adjective (used only before nouns or in idioms or compounds) and not a quantifier, meaning smaller, slighter, less important . . . as in _the lesser evil_, _James the Lesser_,  the _lesser-spotted skrewt_ . However, the sentence is very unidiomatic, so I'll rephrase: _There are far fewer seats in this room than there are next door._

Comment: You may find English Language Learners more useful for answering basic English language questions such as this.

Comment: Could be asked on ELL.stackexchange.com
 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search provides [the solution](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2012/08/less-or-fewer/).

*So the general rule is that if you’re talking about an amount of something that can’t be counted, it’s **less** and if you’re talking about a number of people or things, it’s **fewer**. Another way to remember the main distinction is to think along the following lines: not as much = less, not as many = fewer."*

You can find more examples [here](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/less-or-fewer). You should now know the answer to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you mean : "there are more seats in the other room".

In that case, you should say "fewer", or "by far fewer".

But you could say : " ... are much less comfortable than .."

**Basically, "less" is qualitative, "fewer" quantitative.**

However, some users - not me - allow : "Eat less biscuits !".

Comment: But I'd guess you'd use 'one less reason to . . .' rather than 'one fewer reason to . . .'?

Comment: There is *less* water in this tub. Qualitative? No, quantitative, but used for mass nouns, things that are generally measurable, but uncountable.

Comment: Ok so basically fewer should be used for count nouns.  But can we say "there is much less pie in this pan than in the other?"

Comment: Yes. There are `fewer` grains of sand in the bucket, but there is `less` sand in the bucket. :-)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree with your comment immediately above - but aren't reasons countable, as discussed in your other comment?

Comment: @TrevorD Yes. Another pseudo-rule (though it works maybe 95% of the time).